# Dojo FilteringSelect Dijit clone

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to clone a FilteringSelect object and place it inside a new Dom Node.

```
<button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Add Relation
     <script type="dojo/method" data-dojo-event="onClick" data-dojo-args="evt">
var domConstr = require("dojo/dom-construct"); // get the dom creator
var dom = require("dojo/dom"); // get the dom
var attr = require("dojo/dom-attr");
var lang = require("dojo/_base/lang");  
var node = dijit.byId("far_mt_accountbundle_movementtype_toAccount");
var newnode = lang.clone(node);
```

**This results in the error:**
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined

Thank you for any suggestions.